# Get Console application output to xml file and save the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, http, console-application

My ASP.Net console application produces a xml output , how can I create a xml file and save it ?

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
```

{
class Program
{
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
var TicketTask = await createTicket();
var TicketTask2 = await createTicket2();
}

```
    async static Task<string> createTicket2()
    {
        var content = "unknown error";
        using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "http://10/sap-lve/"))
            {
                try
                {
                    var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("an:s"));
                    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

                    String str1 = @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><s:Body><Get_api_version xmlns='http://e.s.a.com'/></s:Body></s:Envelope>";

                    request.Content = new StringContent(str1, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"); ;
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/xml");
                    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    //Console.WriteLine(response);
                    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Result);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    content = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
        return content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a XmlDocument from the xml string and use its Save Method.

```
string s = "<xml><sample></sample></xml>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(s);
doc.Save("myfilename.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks , that solved it!